# How can I buy in the PS Store with an EntroPay card?

Tags: psn

This process used to be sweet, but now I just can't buy anything.

All I get is ***The funds could not be added to your wallet*** message.

Does anybody know if it is still possible to buy things from the PS Store with an EntroPay card? If so, how?

Answer (score 2):

AFAIK Sony blocked Entropay cards.

Rumors says that it was possible to get the content using an Entropay card and then cancel the transaction, so you got the game but never payied for it, others says that Entropay wasn't sending the money, so Sony blocked. But those are just rumors.

Comment: Thanks for the information ... two months ago I was able to buy some updates for Assassin's Creed... but today I can't buy anything.

Comment: I just recently got an email from EntroPay support and they state that some users have had problems with PSN transactions. In fact they state that 'maybe' PSN is conducting address validation with every card transaction and that feature is not supported by EntroPay. But the thing is the 'maybe' word used in their answer ... so they themselves are not even sure about this.